# How can I make my glob work for cogs on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, discord, discord.py, ubuntu-18.04

I'm very new to Unix/Linux systems, I programmed this on my Windows machine so it works just fine, and I looked at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and got very confused.

Here is my glob code:

```py
COGS = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./lib/cogs/*.py")]
```

In advanced, I appreciate your answers, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what format your output is but I am guessing that your `path.split("\\")` is causing your issue, as Windows uses `\`.  I get a list of my cogs by simply changing this to `path.split("/")`, as linux uses `/` as a path separator

or use `os.sep`